# Java & Azure Table Storage: Can't obtain entity property values other than the PK or RK - other properties return NULL

Tags: java, azure

Let's say I have a table called ImportantData set up in Azure, that looks like this:

| PartitionKey | RowKey | AssociatedData1 | AssociatedData2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MMBI | I_MMBI_XX0099888000 | 12345678 | ABCDEFG |

I want to be able to retrieve the value for property AssociatedData1, for a given entity. However, no matter what I try I'm only able to retrieve the PartitionKey or the RowKey - despite being able to use a filter condition on the AssociatedData1 property.

I have a class set up to hold the data I retrieve from Azure, that looks kind of like this:

```
public class ImportantData extends TableServiceEntity {

    String PartitionKey;
    String RowKey;
    String AssociatedData1;

    public ImportantData(String partitionKey, String rowKey, String associatedData1) {
        PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        RowKey = rowKey;
        AssociatedData1 = associatedData1;
    }

    public ImportantData() {
    }

    public String getAssociatedData1() {
        return AssociatedData1;
    }

    public void setAssociatedData1(String associatedData1) {
        AssociatedData1 = associatedData1;
    }
```

And the code that is running the query looks like this:

```
public void runQuery(URI uri, String token) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException {

    StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(token);

    CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(uri,credentials);

    CloudTable table = tableClient.getTableReference("ImportantData");

    boolean exists = table.exists();
    System.out.println(exists);

    TableQuery<ImportantData> partitionScanQuery =  TableQuery.from(ImportantData.class).where((TableQuery.generateFilterCondition("AssociatedData1", TableQuery.QueryComparisons.EQUAL, "12345678")));

    for (ImportantData entity : table.execute(partitionScanQuery)) {
        System.out.println(entity.getPartitionKey() + " | " + entity.getAssociatedData1());
    }
}
```

All I get in return from the console is as below:

`true`

`MMBI | null`

Any advice on how I can retrieve the actual value in AssociatedData1, instead of null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I seem to have found the solution. Rather than be one of those horrid people who solve their own problems and don't say what they did I'll post my solution. I think the libraries I was using were out of date (or less easy to use), Microsoft have provided a new one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-data-tables</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The below code works for me using the above maven dependency. If anyone wants an example of connecting with a SAS Token instead of a connection string as well, here
you go:

```
public void solution(String endpoint, String sas) {
        final String tableName = "ImportantData";
        final String AssociatedData1 = "AssociatedData1";
        
        TableServiceClient tableServiceClient = new TableServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .sasToken(sas)
                .buildClient();

        TableClient tableClient = tableServiceClient.getTableClient(tableName);

        ListEntitiesOptions options = new ListEntitiesOptions().setFilter(AssociatedData1 + " eq '12345678'");

        // Loop through the results, displaying information about the entities.
        tableClient.listEntities(options, null, null).forEach(tableEntity -> {
            System.out.println(tableEntity.getPartitionKey() +
                    " " + tableEntity.getRowKey() +
                    "\t" + tableEntity.getProperty("AssociatedData1"));
        });
    }
```